# AWS Sam: Failed to create/update the stack Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sam

I am trying to build a S3 supported test app with AWS Sam. Below is the content.

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  patientcheckout

  Sample SAM Template for patientcheckout

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20
    Runtime: java11
    MemorySize: 512

Resources:
  PatientCheckoutBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: "!Sub ${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}"
  PatientCheckoutFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: patientcheckout
      Handler: com.yohan.lambda.PatientCheckoutLambda::handler
      Policies:
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3 # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref PatientCheckoutBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

The app can be built with `sam build` succesfully. When trying to deploy, we end up with this error.

```
D:\pop\awslambda\patientcheckout>sam deploy --guided

Configuring SAM deploy
======================

        Looking for config file [samconfig.toml] :  Found
        Reading default arguments  :  Success

        Setting default arguments for 'sam deploy'
        =========================================
        Stack Name [patientcheckout]: patientcheckout
        AWS Region [us-east-1]:
        #Shows you resources changes to be deployed and require a 'Y' to initiate deploy
        Confirm changes before deploy [y/N]:
        #SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
        Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]:
        Save arguments to configuration file [Y/n]:
        SAM configuration file [samconfig.toml]:
        SAM configuration environment [default]:

        Looking for resources needed for deployment: Found!

                Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1hmnzbuee9816
                A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml

        Saved arguments to config file
        Running 'sam deploy' for future deployments will use the parameters saved above.
        The above parameters can be changed by modifying samconfig.toml
        Learn more about samconfig.toml syntax at
        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html


        Deploying with following values
        ===============================
        Stack name                   : patientcheckout
        Region                       : us-east-1
        Confirm changeset            : False
        Deployment s3 bucket         : aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1hmnzbuee9816
        Capabilities                 : ["CAPABILITY_IAM"]
        Parameter overrides          : {}
        Signing Profiles             : {}

Initiating deployment
=====================

Waiting for changeset to be created..

CloudFormation stack changeset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                     LogicalResourceId             ResourceType                  Replacement
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                         PatientCheckoutBucket         AWS::S3::Bucket               N/A
+ Add                         PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   AWS::IAM::Role                N/A
+ Add                         PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   AWS::Lambda::Permission       N/A
                              entPermission
+ Add                         PatientCheckoutFunction       AWS::Lambda::Function         N/A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Changeset created successfully. arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:716460586643:changeSet/samcli-deploy1624953681/834f8797-6047-4d72-b368-9d54ea9783ac


2021-06-29 13:31:31 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from changeset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                ResourceType                  LogicalResourceId             ResourceStatusReason
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::IAM::Role                PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   Resource creation Initiated
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::IAM::Role                PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   -
CREATE_COMPLETE               AWS::IAM::Role                PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   -
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Function         PatientCheckoutFunction       -
CREATE_COMPLETE               AWS::Lambda::Function         PatientCheckoutFunction       -
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Function         PatientCheckoutFunction       Resource creation Initiated
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Permission       PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   -
                                                            entPermission
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Permission       PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   Resource creation Initiated
                                                            entPermission
CREATE_COMPLETE               AWS::Lambda::Permission       PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   -
                                                            entPermission
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS          AWS::CloudFormation::Stack    patientcheckout               The following resource(s)
                                                                                          failed to create:
                                                                                          [PatientCheckoutBucket].
                                                                                          Rollback requested by user.
CREATE_FAILED                 AWS::S3::Bucket               PatientCheckoutBucket         Bad Request (Service:
                                                                                          Amazon S3; Status Code:
                                                                                          400; Error Code: 400 Bad
                                                                                          Request; Request ID:
                                                                                          7NRVBFEJSMBTGM0G; S3
                                                                                          Extended Request ID: 9tGgby
                                                                                          nxYIq05EvkwIF8KZgbQNoGEOfkI
                                                                                          Hsl+DoKYcGSyh1Ti4Et/pVZG/uS
                                                                                          0LfgFR+WYyZV++k=; Proxy:
                                                                                          null)
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::S3::Bucket               PatientCheckoutBucket         -
DELETE_COMPLETE               AWS::S3::Bucket               PatientCheckoutBucket         -
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Permission       PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   -
                                                            entPermission
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::Lambda::Function         PatientCheckoutFunction       -
DELETE_COMPLETE               AWS::Lambda::Permission       PatientCheckoutFunctionS3Ev   -
                                                            entPermission
DELETE_COMPLETE               AWS::Lambda::Function         PatientCheckoutFunction       -
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS            AWS::IAM::Role                PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   -
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE             AWS::CloudFormation::Stack    patientcheckout               -
DELETE_COMPLETE               AWS::IAM::Role                PatientCheckoutFunctionRole   -
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: patientcheckout, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The following resource(s) failed to create: [PatientCheckoutBucket].`

To fix, provide a simpler bucket name. One that follows the naming rules outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html

Here is an example using template parameters so whatever you enter for `sam deploy --guided` will be saved to the `.toml` file. And while we're in there, lets use the Bucket Ref for the `S3ReadPolicy`:

```
Parameters:
  MyBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: "default-bucketname"

Resources:
  PatientCheckoutBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "prefix-${MyBucketName}-suffix"

  PatientCheckoutFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: patientcheckout
      Handler: com.yohan.lambda.PatientCheckoutLambda::handler
      Policies:
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref PatientCheckoutBucket
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3 # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref PatientCheckoutBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```