# Error: Failed to create/update the stack: resume-stack, Waiter StackUpdateComplete failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to reproduce, step-by-step, the instructions on this video **"Install AWS SAM CLI and create an S3 Bucket"** from youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeLdSO6LHW0m, on how to create an S3 Bucket using SAM as Infrastructure as Code.

I have followed the video's instructions, step-by-step; however, when I run the aws-vault command to create the S3 bucket, I receive the following error message:

> 

```
% aws-vault exec my-user --no-session -- sam deploy         
File with same data already exists at resume-stack/445f94158914d32693176a0725a98472, skipping upload

    Deploying with following values
    ===============================
    Stack name                   : resume-stack
    Region                       : us-east-1
    Confirm changeset            : False
    Disable rollback             : False
    Deployment s3 bucket         : aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-rzqvgcwwyja9
    Capabilities                 : ["CAPABILITY_IAM"]
    Parameter overrides          : {}
    Signing Profiles             : {}

Initiating deployment
=====================
Uploading to resume-stack/e89cc5a3136547707b1bcb1032c2d3b0.template  1350 / 1350  (100.00%)

Waiting for changeset to be created..
CloudFormation stack changeset
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                             LogicalResourceId                     ResourceType                          Replacement                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                                 MyWebsite                             AWS::S3::Bucket                       N/A                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Changeset created successfully. arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:053806060854:changeSet/samcli-deploy1671330287/7674b5d9-9fb6-4187-8208-150664530af4


2022-12-17 21:25:00 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from stack operations (refresh every 0.5 seconds)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                        ResourceType                          LogicalResourceId                     ResourceStatusReason                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                    AWS::S3::Bucket                       MyWebsite                             -                                   
CREATE_FAILED                         AWS::S3::Bucket                       MyWebsite                             my-resume-website already exists    
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS           AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            resume-stack                          The following resource(s) failed to 
                                                                                                                  create: [MyWebsite].                
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            resume-stack                          -                                   
_PROGRESS                                                                                                                                             
DELETE_COMPLETE                       AWS::S3::Bucket                       MyWebsite                             -                                   
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE              AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            resume-stack                          -                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: resume-stack, Waiter StackUpdateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

My IAM user has the following permissions:

- AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator
- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- AWSLambda_FullAccess
- AWSIQFullAccess

My template.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  cloud-resume

  Sample SAM Template for cloud-resume

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128

Resources:
  MyWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties: 
      BucketName: my-resume-website
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

I have deleted the stacks in CloudFormation and the all the S3 buckets created after running the sam deploy and re-run the sam deploy with using different names for the stack and the s3 bucket name in the template.yaml file, but I still get the same error message.

I also tried changing the resources block of code in template.yaml file as stated by this previous question: [AWS Sam: Failed to create/update the stack Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174860/aws-sam-failed-to-create-update-the-stack-error)

I changed the stanza in the template.yaml file from this:

```
Resources:
  MyWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties: 
      BucketName: my-resume-website
```

To the format recommended in the in the stackoverflow question mentioned above:

```
Parameters:
  MyBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: "resume-website"

Resources:
  PatientCheckoutBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "prefix-${MyBucketName}-suffix"
```

This works, and it adds the S3 bucket successfully, but it names the bucket as "prefix-resume-website-suffix".

When I remove "prefix-" and "-suffix" from the BucketName, the sam deploy fails again.

How can I add the s3 bucket as "resume-website" without the "prefix-" and "-suffix"?

I would sincerely appreciate anyone's help with this.

Best,

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some resources on AWS need to be globally unique (eg s3 bucket names) ie not used on AWS anywhere else, and some need to be unique just within your AWS account and a specific region (eg lambda & SQS names)

I suspect you're running into issues with bucket names that have been previously taken, what I would suggest is a simple naming convention to avoid naming conflicts on all resources (especially for production resources within Companies with multiple developers to avoid naming collisions, and to make it easier to see which resources belong to which stacks at a glance) is to prefix the resource name with your stack-name, eg:

```
Resources:
  # s3 Buckets
  MyResumeWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
     BucketName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-my-resume-website

  # lambdas
   SomeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-SomeLambda

  # SQSs
  SomeSQS:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-SomeSQS
```

Comment: Yes! I felt so stupid for not realizing this, but this indeed was the problem - not having a unique bucket name! Thanks!